# packages error \usepackage [Glenn]{fncychap}

Tags: errors

When I compile my code I got this error. Someone could please suggest. A snapshot of log file is attached.

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\let\circledS\undefined % here - PS
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{scalerel}
%\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
%\textwidth=450pt\oddsidemargin=0pt
%\geometry{verbose,a4paper,tmargin=25mm,bmargin=25mm,lmargin=42mm,rmargin=25mm}
%\newgeometry{top=1in,bottom=1in,outer=1in,inner=2in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[pdftex, breaklinks=true, colorlinks=true,linkcolor={blue},citecolor={red}]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linktocpage}
\begin{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is explained on the line starting with the exclamation mark

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package graphicx.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.25 \usepackage
                [Glenn]{fncychap}
?
```

So the error is not related to `fncychap`, but about the `graphicx` package. *Option clash* means that the package has been loaded twice with a different set of options.

For internal reasons, TeX has read ahead before realizing the error about the option clash, so you see it stopped when the last token it has read is `\usepackage`.

By the way, you're loading `subfigure` that's obsolete and you do

```
\let\circledS\undefined
```

in order to avoid an error related to `amssymb`. But you also get two warnings that should be self-explanatory

```latex
Package mathdesign/mdbch Warning: Package 'amssymb' shouldn't be used in conjon
ction with package mdbch, on input line 34.

Package mathdesign/mdbch Warning: Package 'amsfonts' shouldn't be used in conjo
nction with package mdbch, on input line 34.
```

which simply means: don't try to fix something that should *not* be fixed that way. Remove the call to `amssymb`, instead. The `mdbch` package is a subsidiary package related to `mathdesign`, as the warning explains.

The warning about `\@parboxrestore` can be avoided by loading `csquotes` after `lineno`.

Finally, never pass the `pdftex` option to `hyperref`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't load the same package (graphicx in your example) multiple times, especially not with different options. If this is fixed, the document compiles:

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\let\circledS\undefined % here - PS
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
%\usepackage{scalerel}
%\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
%\textwidth=450pt\oddsidemargin=0pt
%\geometry{verbose,a4paper,tmargin=25mm,bmargin=25mm,lmargin=42mm,rmargin=25mm}
%\newgeometry{top=1in,bottom=1in,outer=1in,inner=2in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[pdftex, breaklinks=true, colorlinks=true,linkcolor={blue},citecolor={red}]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linktocpage}
\begin{document}

foo

\end{document}
```